# Reshape Tensorflow ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create my train dataset using ImageDataGenerator. There are two different folders which are containing images for separate labels. When I started to train, I get an error about shapes:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

How can I solve this problem? Original size of each image is 100x100 and they in RGB form.

```
 datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 5,
    zoom_range = (0.95, 0.95),
    horizontal_flip = False,
    vertical_flip = False,
    data_format = 'channels_last',
    validation_split = 0.0,
    dtype = tf.float32
    )

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('sign_data/', 
                                              target_size=(48,48),
                                              batch_size=4, color_mode='grayscale', 
                                              class_mode='sparse', shuffle=True, 
                                              subset='training', seed=123) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, data_format="channels_last", padding='same', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10)
```

I alos tried to use target_size=(48,48,1)

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('sign_data/', 
                                          target_size=(48,48,1),
                                          batch_size=4, color_mode='grayscale', 
                                          class_mode='sparse', shuffle=True, 
                                          subset='training', seed=123)
```

Error is

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (48,48,1) into shape (48,48,1,1)
```

Comment: Its not about the target size, if you use sparse class mode, you need to use an appropriate loss (like sparse categorical crossentropy)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> if you use `sparse` class mode, you need
> to use `sparse categorical crossentropy` loss (paraphrased from Dr.Snoopy)

Working code as shown below

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 5,
    zoom_range = (0.95, 0.95),
    horizontal_flip = False,
    vertical_flip = False,
    data_format = 'channels_last',
    validation_split = 0.0,
    dtype = tf.float32
    )

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('sign_data/', 
                                              target_size=(48,48),
                                              batch_size=4, color_mode='grayscale', 
                                              class_mode='sparse', shuffle=True, 
                                              subset='training', seed=123) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, data_format="channels_last", padding='same', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10)
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is for data with one class as label, and it is an integer (or string). `categorical_crossentropy` is for labels that are encoded as one-hot-like vectors (one-hot vector, or multi-label).